# Isolating Docker environment from host

Tags: node.js, docker, next.js, docker-compose

I would like to create a container such that when I update the code on the host machine, it updates the code in the container as well (I mounted my project directory as a volume in the container to resolve this part).

However, I would like to know if there was a way to do this such that any project dependencies installed in the container will **not** be copied to the host machine.

Comment: If you can install project dependencies outside of the mounted directory, they won't be installed in the host directory. You can then mount the host directory as read only to ensure that no changes are made outside the container.

Comment: Thank you @HansKilian. So in my case I can copy my 'package.json' file into a directory, then I mount the code as a subdirectory in the container as read only?